# UITableView choppy scrolling when appending new cells coming back from network

Tags: ios, objective-c

In scrollViewDidScroll, I check if the table view is scroll close enough to the bottom, if it is, a network request is executed to fetch new data from the server, and when the network request is successful I updated the data model and then updated the tableView by calling [tableView reloadData].

The symptom is the scrolling performance is choppy at the moment when the network request is finished and new items get added to the table.

Does anyone know what could cause the issue?

Comment: How many items are in the model that drives the table?

Comment: Could be a few thousands, but I saw the jerky scrolling issue as early as when there are < 100 items get fetched from the server. But the issue doesn't repro very reliably, so I'm not sure how to start debugging this.

Comment: How much data is in the download? How long does it take to process? Is it being run on the main thread? Is it being placed into Core Data or some other data store? The choppy scrolling is if you scroll down, start the network request and then start scrolling up as the request completes?

Comment: If the issue is only for the brief moment while iOS is redrawing the table and you are scrolling the table at the same time, I'd think that is to be expected; does it smooth out after a moment?

Comment: @Wain: network result will be parsed into core data, but it all happens in a background thread. yes, I think more precisely the choppy scrolling happens when the network request finish and the table is redrawn.

Comment: @RickTrapp Yes, it will smooth out after a moment

Comment: So, if it's really a problem, you can change your logic for deciding whether to reloadData on whether the table view is still scrolled to the bottom (i.e. the new data would actually be seen). If not, don't reload until the scrolling has stopped.

Comment: Have you seen any pattern where it is more choppy on an iPhone 4, less/not choppy on iPhone 5?

Comment: You're either not properly dequeuing your `UITableViewCell`, or your performing an action on the main thread that is causing a hang as your table view is lazily loading more cells.

Answer (score 1):

don't reload the whole table view

just add your data to dataSource and call [tableView:insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation]

Example ..

```
// addNewDataToDataSource(data)

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```